# WKWebView, delegate method for knowing when the DOM is ready in iOS 10

Tags: ios, swift, dom

I'm looking through the documentation for [WKUIDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/reference/webkit/wkuidelegate)  and I see there's a method for knowing when the DOM has been closed successfully. Is there a way to know when the DOM has successfully been loaded so that I can begin interacting with it in JavaScript?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a WKUserScript with an injection time of `atDocumentEnd` to run JavaScript at the end of the loading process. However, some subresources may not have loaded, so if you want to wait until the very end, you will have to use the WKNavigationDelegate's `didFinish` and call `evaluateJavaScript`.

Comment: Thanks @matt - I do wish there was more out there on WKWebView/JavaScript integration in general. I'd pay for that content. This helps.

Comment: Well, there isn't much to know. WKScriptMessageHandler to pass from JavaScript out to Swift, WKUserScript and `evaluateJacaScript` to pass from Swift to JavaScript.